# Assign multiword string to a bash array element

Tags: arrays, bash

My goal is to take the first word from a string and assign it to a bash  array, `FIRSTWORD{i]` and take the rest of the string and put it into another array, `REST[i]` where `i` is an integer counter.

I tried this approach:  (Note: strictly speaking `tmp` is  just for debug)

**CORRECTION:** I left the indexes off the `string` vars.  Should be `string[1]` and `string[2]`.

```
string[1]="One Two Three Four"
string[2]="Five Six Seven Eight"
# etc etc

for ((i=0; i < ${#string[@]}; i++ ))
do
   set -- ${string[i]}
   FIRSTWORD[i]=$1  
   tmp="${*:2}" 
   REST[i]=$tmp
   echo $tmp
   echo ${REST[i]}
done
```

`REST[i]` turns out to equal `"Two"` but`tmp` equals `"one tswo three"`

So I tried:

```
IFS=$'\n';  REST[i]="${*:2}"; IFS=$' ';
```

No joy.

So, how do I accomplish this task?

Comment: I got "Two Three Four" for both echo statements (after I commented out the second definition of string)

Comment: Oops.  Those were string[1] and string[2].  Example corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my answer.  I changed:

```
REST[i]=$tmp
```

to

```
REST[i]="$tmp"
```

And now the data read into rest is kept together.

I assume this has to do with bash and the command line splitting and globbing data.